# Graphic problem while install ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics

Hello i am this motherboard Gigabyte GA-Z170X-GAMING 7 and asus nvidia gtx970 oc graphic card.I change boot to start from cd.I press install ubuntu and after that restarts and i loose the graphics on monitor.What can cause this problem??I tried also from onboard graphics and the problme still.So i figure that the motherboard cause this problem installation.

Answer (score 0):

I work all days with similar issues. You probably only need to install the correct driver (http://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/77844/en-us) . If you can get to terminal mode with <kbd>crtl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> or if you can ssh to your machine. 
download this driver with

```
sudo wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/343.22/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-343.22.run
```

after that give it access to be executable with

```
chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-343.22.run.
```

before running it stop lightdm.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

then

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-343.22.run
```

accept all but 32 bit version, but everything else yes. 
then just run

```
sudo reboot
```

your computer should work now.